# Flipped Normals after export

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, export, normals

My problem is that after I export my meshes to Ue4 it shows me that the normals are flipped. I tried both way, flipped and not flipped normals. This is what I get every time.
Any tips what I might be missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like maybe it's culling the front faces instead of the back faces. Try checking in Ue4 for "backface-cull", "front cull" or "two sided faces" and see if they do anything.

Comment: Also, what file format are you exporting to?

Comment: I exported it in .fbx. I have since resolved the issue. Pretty simple, flipped the normal until it finally went through. It was just a bug I guess. Thanks for the help anyway, im sure it'll be useful in the near future. Since I have this problem whenever i boolean meshes